# The variable scope in Groovy Closure (global variable and function parameter have same name)

Tags: groovy

I am new to Groovy and confusing about the variable scope in closure.

For example, the code below works fine. It prints two 5.

```
def x = 10
def y = 25

def myfunc(x) {
  return {
      println(x)
      insideFunc(x)
  }
}

def insideFunc(x) {
    println(x)
}

closureFunc = myfunc(5)

closureFunc.call()
```

But the code below would show error:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: x for class. Why? I thought the insideFunc can access the global variable 'x'?

```
def x = 10
def y = 25

def myfunc(x) {
  return {
      println(x)
      insideFunc()
  }
}

def insideFunc() {
    println(x)
}

closureFunc = myfunc(5)

closureFunc.call()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the second script is due to how the script is executed. `x` is local-scoped in the `run` method. That should become evident when one looks at what the script turns into when it's executed. From groovyConsole, the following is what "Inspect AST" displays (this is incomplete):

```
public class script1526974299557 extends groovy.lang.Script { 

    ...

    public java.lang.Object run() {
        java.lang.Object x = 10
        java.lang.Object y = 25
        closureFunc = this.myfunc(5)
        closureFunc.call()
    }

    public java.lang.Object myfunc(java.lang.Object x) {
        return { 
            this.println(x)
            this.insideFunc()
        }
    }

    public java.lang.Object insideFunc() {
        this.println(x)
    }
}
```

Clearly, `x` is out of scope for `insideFunc()`.

Regarding the first version, however, things look different. As `insideFunc()` takes a parameter, it's argument is carried by the closure:

```
public class script1526974614817 extends groovy.lang.Script { 

    ...

    public java.lang.Object myfunc(java.lang.Object x) {
        return { 
            this.println(x)
            this.insideFunc(x)
        }
    }

    public java.lang.Object insideFunc(java.lang.Object x) {
        this.println(x)
    }
}
```